# Cómo filtrar la data obtenida con AJAX de un archivo JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax

OK apenas logré obtener el archivo con el código de abajo pero solo me interesa el valor del sicad2 del item USD de mi archivo JSON que está alojado en este enlace [https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json][1]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<button type="button" onClick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p>Click the button several times to see if the time changes, or if the file is cached.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json?t=" + Math.random(), true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Intenté con `JSON.parse(this.responsetext);`  pero es peor porque antes al menos sabía que obtenía el archivo completo sin formato (llaves y comas...) despues de hacer eso del parse me da cmo resultado [Object, Object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo bien el proceso, el problema es que al hacer el JSON.parse tu variable contendrá un objeto JSON y este no se puede escribir dentro de un HTML, ese valor lo podrías ver bien en consola:

`console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText))`

Ahora bien, para obtener solo el valor que requieres es cuestión de adentrarse más en el JSON:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.parse(this.responseText)["USD"]["sicad2"];
```

Con esto debería bastar.